# No me carga componente Angular2 Tour Of Heroes

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas, hace poco comencé a programar y empece el tutorial de AngularJs(2). Estaba haciendo el tutorial del Tour de heroes de la documentacion oficial pero no me carga el componente y se queda la pantalla en Loading.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

  providers: [HeroService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TorneoHeroes</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';

import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

hero.detail.component.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }               from '@angular/common';

import { Hero }         from './hero';
import { HeroService }  from './hero.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ]
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

hero.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './heroes.component.css' ]
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  gotoDetail(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedHero.id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes abrir el dev tools `F12` y ver qué errores obtienes?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [tour] del sitio y lee  [cómo crear una buena pregunta]  (http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: con el dev tools me tira esto : Error loading http://localhost:4200/main.js  localhost:4200:18:53
El uso de getPreventDefault() es obsoleto.  Use defaultPrevented en su lugar.  localhost:4200

Comment: Estas usando angulr-cli? puedes pegar info de el archivo aqui? y si no lo estas usando, pruebalo, que te crea un proyecto por defecto y de ahi empiezas a marinear ;)

Comment: @AlejandroLora si uso angular-cli, el tutorial que utilizo es la doc. oficial.

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura  con el dev tools me tira esto : Error loading localhost:4200/main.js localhost:4200:18:53 El uso de getPreventDefault() es obsoleto. Use defaultPrevented en su lugar. localhost:4200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentas arriba, usas Angular CLI, puedes pegar el archivo aquí y le echamos un ojo?

Otra cosa que veo es muchos fallos de código, no se si al copiar te has liado o realmente ese es el código, en cuyo caso es un poco caótico.

Te adjunto una imagen y te describo algunos fallos que veo por si te ayudan a arreglar el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Ese CSS debería ser implementado con AngularCLI, aunque no es motivo del break.
2. ¿Dónde has declarado app-root? No lo veo por ningún lado, creo que deberías renombarlo en el app component o bien usar el selector que has declarado, , esto si es causa de fallo total de la app.
3. Usando webpack embebido en angular cli, no necesitas los moduleId, de hecho, te darían error a cierto punto probablemente.
4. Aquí es donde me confundo si es que has copiado mal o tienes un lío grande, porque estás creado dos veces la clase AppComponent, todo igual menos el selector y en el mismo archivo, te sugeriría borrar la segunda completamente.

Creo que corrigiendo eso, te puede correr la app sin problemas, y si no, pega la config del angular cli y alguna captura del error de consola que obtienes, y te podremos seguir echando un cable ;)

**EDITADO**

No veo tu archivo main.ts, lo has creado no? Si es que no, el contenido sería este:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por contestar, recien edite la publicacion, arregle algunas cosas pero me sigue sin cargar el componente y se queda en Loading. La consola con angular-cli no me tira ningun error ,solo webpack: Compiled successfully.
Saludos

Comment: Te edito la respuesta y me dices si te funciona ;)